# Can element ignore height values of properties before it?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 elements sharing the same class `.cta`. The CTA inside of `.casino-box` looks great, however the one inside of `.header-box` is accounting for the 165px of space taken up by `.top-nav-bar` and `.nav-bar`.

How can I get the top CTA to ignore the added spacing of those two nav bars, without having to split the css code for the CTAs?

[Link to CodePen](http://codepen.io/bmoneruiux/pen/mJbvQv/)

```
.cta {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -80px;
}

.cta h1 {
  color: #fff;
  weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px black;
}

.cta .button {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px black;
}
.cta .button:hover {
  color: #90281F;
  background: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.cta hr {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: Set `margin-top: -205px;` inside `.header-box .cta` and all two blocks are going to be aligned in center.

Comment: Thank you for that. That was insanely obvious, and yet I had a total brain fart while coding. Can you set that as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set negative `margin-top` with the height of `.top-nav-bar and .nav-bar` plus your normal margin so the two div could be aligned in center. In this case it would probably be as following:

```
.header-box .cta {
   margin-top: -205px;
}
```